# xslt select element only by attribute

Tags: xml, xslt

How to select in the following xml all elements by attribute 'type=a'?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<PLAYLIST>
    <ITEM type="a">
        <ARTIST>Pixies</ARTIST>
    </ITEM>
    <TEST>
        <ARTIST type="a">Lambchop</ARTIST>
    </TEST>         
</PLAYLIST>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The XPath expression:

```
//*[@type="a"]
```

will select any element that has a `type` attribute with the value of "a", anywhere in the XML document.

**Note**:
You have tagged this question as `XSLT`. The answer above may or may not be useful in an XSLT stylesheet. It depends on what you want to accomplish by the transformation.

Comment: with respect to your note, what Iam looking for was '<xsl:apply-templates select="//*[@type='a']"/>'